# SQL Windowing Aggregation and Counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am using Redshift/Postgres DB. Consider the following table:

```sh
    +---------------------------------------+
    |              FunkyUsers               |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+
    |acc_num| user_id |   date   | is_valid |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200201 |    true  |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200201 |    true  |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200311 |    true  |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |
    |   a1  |    u3   | 20111201 |    true  |
    |   a1  |    u3   | 20111201 |    true  |
    |   a1  |    u3   | 20111201 |    true  |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+
```

I like to have the following output:

```sh
    +--------------------------------------------------+
    |                  FunkyUsers                      |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |acc_num| user_id |   date   | is_valid |  count   |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200201 |    true  |    2     |
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200201 |    true  |    2     |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u1   | 20200311 |    true  |    2     |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |    0     |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |    0     |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20200201 |   false  |    0     |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20111201 |    true  |    1     |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20111201 |    true  |    1     |
    |   a1  |    u2   | 20111201 |    true  |    1     |
    +-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Description:

- Please note the partition `acc_num, user_id`
- Please note the subpartition within the above partition which is the `date`
- When `is_valid` is true for a `(partition, subpartition)` increment the `count` for that `(partition)`
- Finally the `is_valid` will have the same value for each row within the same `(partition, subpartition)`

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some (very) ancient roots, they are substantially different products

Comment: So it is postgress on redshift. We can consider a solution for postgress.

Comment: "*postgres on redshift*" doesn't make sense. It's either Postgres or Redshift. Quote from the [Redshift manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html) "*Do not assume that the semantics of elements that Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have in common are identical*"

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the reply. So the count is incremented for each partition (i.e acc_num, user_id). So for that partition, subpartition there are 2 valid states.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I'll delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to count distinct dates for is_valid = 1 for a user.
You can use window function count with distinct parameter for date.

```
select 
    acc_num, user_id, date, is_valid, 
    count(distinct case when is_valid then date end) over (partition by acc_num, user_id, is_valid)
from FunkyUsers
```

I'm told it's not possible to use distinct in window functions in Redshift.
So, you can use this query:

```
with
counts as
(
    SELECT acc_num, user_id, is_valid, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN is_valid THEN date END) as count
    FROM FunkyUsers
    GROUP BY acc_num, user_id, is_valid
)
SELECT f.*, c.count
FROM FunkyUsers f
LEFT JOIN counts c
    ON f.acc_num = c.acc_num
    AND f.user_id = c.user_id
    AND f.is_valid = c.is_valid
```

Comment: you cannot use `distinct` inside window function.

Comment: thank you for the reply but it returns 3 instead of 2.

Comment: I forgot adding is_Valid to partition. Can you try again?

Comment: Unfortunately, it says window function is not supported.

Comment: Then, added another solution. I'm sure it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `sum` with partitioning:

```
select acc_num, user_id, date, is_valid, 
       sum(case when is_valid then 1 end) over(partition by acc_num, user_id, date)
from FunkyUsers
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but it returns 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @Stacky 3 what?

Comment: No worries, Sabri's solution worked. Thanks again for help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`count(distinct)` is not supported.  But a simple work-around is to use `row_number()`:

```
select fu.*,
       sum(case when is_valid and seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by acc_num, user_id order by date) as count
from (select fu.*,
             row_number() over (partition by acc_num, user_id, date order by date) as seqnum
      from funkyusers fu
     ) fu;
```

This is much simpler than a solution that uses aggregation and `join` and it should have better performance as well.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. By the time I received yours, I had tried the other solution and it worked for my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Stacky . . . This is a much simpler solution and should have better performance as well.